# Generating openAPI(swagger) spec files automatically in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, swagger, openapi

I am trying to figure out how can i generate the openAPI json or yaml file automatically in my php application. As of now, i saw little to none docs on it, so i pretty much in the dark on this issue.
Is there some way/package/anything else im missing?
Im using also laravel 4.2
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend this package: https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php
It generates OpenAPI json from annotations found in your files. I recommend you to place these annotations in controllers, models and middlewares. Thus you benefit for good documentation in your API code.